# CSS - Wrap text in div only when absolutely needed

Tags: html, css, whitespace, nowrap

I have a checkbox with text next to it in a little pop-up window:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
    <p class="checkbox-label">Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox-label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljh3q7ew/)

The problem is that since I have `.checkbox-wrapper` to be `white-space: nowrap;`, it goes off the pop-up menu. However, if I remove the `white-space: nowrap;`, the text wraps way too soon and doesn't take up all the space in the pop-up window. How can I make it so the text only wraps after it hits 100% of the pop-up div's width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flexbox here, I have attached jsfiddle snippet here.

```css
.box {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 }

 .checkbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
 }

 .checkbox-label {
  color: #2e2e2e;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
  <p class="checkbox-label">Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working. I did make one adjustment to center the wrapper if you're on a larger display and can fit everything in one line: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcw8tvep/)